# How to import Android library module (AAR) using gradle cli

Tags: bash, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar, gradlew

I am developing an Android Library module in AAR format. I found it very troublesome to have to be manually importing the module via Android Studio wizard each time I need to test library changes on an Android sample app. I changed my approach to using a symbolic link and linking the generated AAR on the library side with the AAR on the sample app side and just building and syncing Gradle via Android Studio.

However, this process is still not the best because I need to manually click buttons on Studio to achieve this. What I would like is to write a simple script using Gradle CLI and/or bash that allows me, from the app's side, to import the module into the app from some directory and sync the app's Gradle after importing.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import your library module every time. Make your library as one of the modules and link the dependency between app and library.

Make sure the library is listed at the top of your settings.gradle file, as shown here for a library named "my-library-module":

```
include ':app', ':my-library-module'
```

Open the app module's build.gradle file and add a new line to the dependencies block as shown in the following snippet:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":my-library-module")
}
```

And build using command lines.

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: What I meant was, how to import the library from the library's directory to the app's library directory for the first time using command line options and not the Android Studio import module wizard. You do need to re-import the library each time you make changes otherwise you won't see the changes on app's side and this is why I used the symbolic link approach in order to avoid this.

Comment: If library is included as project dependency then it shall be built every time there is change in source code of library.

Comment: This is not true, because you already imported AAR to app's library directory and this AAR file is not pointing to library's newly generated AAR, which is in its own Android project (and directory). So each time you edit library and build it you get a new AAR which is independent from the one that the app already has. In summary, updating the library's AAR does not update the app's AAR. Feel free to try it out.

Comment: Create a android library module which has 'your library source code' and then 'your app having dependency on this library project' will be using the latest change in your  library code.

Comment: Already tried this approach many times but as I stated previously you never get latest changes when you sync app's gradle (which syncs your AAR's gradle) without reimporting the AAR into app. If this approach worked I wouldn't have bothered to write this thread. I do appreciate the help however, thanks.